# Calling the setter and getter method based on the proto file

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have just started out working with GRPC and having trouble setting and getting a parameter.

Here is how I declared my proto file:

```
syntax="proto3";

package student;

message Student {
  string name = 1;
   int32 age = 2;
}
```

Then I compiled to generate the header and cpp files using the command:

```
protoc -I=./ --cpp_out=./ ./student.proto
```

Now how I set and get the age of the student:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "student.pb.h"

int main() {
      puts("Hello");
      // Now set and get the age
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++ example according to your format (serialization and deserialization):

```
int main()
{
    // Serailization

    student::Student s1;
    s1.set_name("XYZ");
    s1.set_age(20);

    const auto serializedData = s1.SerializeAsString();

    // Send/Store Serialized Data

    // Deserialization

    student::Student s2;
    if ( !s2.ParseFromString( serializedData ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Deserialzation failed!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Name: " << s2.name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Age : " << s2.age() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Name: XYZ
Age : 20
```